# Python idle doesn't print python tensor flow comparison

Tags: comparison

I'm learning deep learning tutorial by daniel bourke in youtube,in this tutorial,i'm now in tensor flow tutorial,now i'm in create two random but the same tensors part,i'm stuck at random_1,random_2,random_1==random_2 part comparing where i am using python idle to learn python,anyone know how to print out comparison in python tensors in python idle because even though i am able to print out tf.Tensors() in python idle but unable to print out comparison of python tensors idle[python idle tensors output[python idle tensors output 2[python tensors idle output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGC5P.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qaiyk.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOIVg.png)

I have try to print out python tensors and comparison of two python tensors in python idle

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not surprising that different code produces different output.  In the IPyNotebook, you rebind the variables to Numpy arrrays and compare the Numpy arrays, which give an array of bools.  In Python, you compare the Tensorflow arrays, which gives a normal boolean answer -- True.  This has nothing to do with IDLE.  Run the tensorflow compare directly with Python and see the result.  PS.  Code and ouput should be in your question, not in images.